Getting version conflicts when trying to add dependencies in my React project
I am trying to add some more dependencies like the react-pdf etc. in my project which is a Django project and I am trying to use react elements too along with it. I am using the webpack to present my react code to my Django using npm build and start Webpack commands, which is giving me a build file which is accepted my Django project.
So far I know that the React elements (packages and dependencies ) are dependent on a package.json file which gives a list of the files that are required or installed in the system according to requirements . If I use the "npm install" then it searches for the package.json file and then the package-lock.json file to install the required mentioned packages and dependencies.
Now, I have even removed the node_modules folder(which contains all the installed dependencies) and the package-lock.json file too, and just have the package.json file, if I try to install the dependencies now, then it giving me a no. of version conflicts among the packages/library names listed in package.json file.
The main issue is the project is already running without any errors in deployment and now when I try to add any other dependency than it is showing version conflict the already running project.
I tried removing the package-lock.json file and the node_modules folder too, for a fresh installation of packages/dependencies but it still got errors.
I've tried editing the package.json files to match the version requirements but still it got issues.
Here is my package.json file :
{
    "name": "u4rad-report",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "http://34.93.156.210/report",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^27.1.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^1.1.0",
        "@jsonforms/core": "^2.5.2",
        "@jsonforms/material-renderers": "^2.5.0",
        "@jsonforms/react": "^3.2.1",
        "@jsonforms/vanilla-renderers": "^2.5.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.3",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.6.7",
        "babel-jest": "^27.4.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
        "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.8",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
        "bfj": "^7.0.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "browserslist": "^4.18.1",
        "camelcase": "^6.2.1",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
        "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
        "googleapis": "^122.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.4.3",
        "jest-resolve": "^27.4.2",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
        "popper": "^1.0.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.4",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.0.1",
        "prompts": "^2.4.2",
        "query-string": "^4.3.4",
        "react": "16.8.0",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap4-modal": "^1.7.5",
        "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
        "react-dom": "16.8.0",
        "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
        "react-share": "^4.4.1",
        "resolve": "^1.20.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
        "semver": "^7.3.5",
        "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
        "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.2",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.2",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
        "build:webpack": "webpack --mode=production",
        "start:webpack": "webpack --watch",
        "dev:webpack": "webpack --mode=development"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
        "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.3.0",
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.3.4",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "crypto": "npm:crypto-browserify",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
        "postcss": "^8.3.6",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
        "resolve-cwd": "^3.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "stream": "npm:stream-browserify",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
        "webpack": "^5.91.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "jest": {
        "roots": [
            "<rootDir>/src"
        ],
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "!src/**/*.d.ts"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
            "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
            "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
            "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
            "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "web.js",
            "js",
            "web.ts",
            "ts",
            "web.tsx",
            "tsx",
            "json",
            "web.jsx",
            "jsx",
            "node"
        ],
        "watchPlugins": [
            "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
            "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
        ],
        "resetMocks": true
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    }
}

and here is one of my errors when I try to add a new dependency or install the previous one's again:
(env) PS E:\ReportingBot\env\Reporting-Bot-main\authsysproject\JS>
npm install
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @jsonforms/react@2.5.2
npm error Found: react@16.8.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"16.8.0" from the root project
npm error   peer react@"^16.0.0" from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@1.1.3
npm error   node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
npm error     @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm error   11 more (@material-ui/core, @material-ui/icons, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^16.12.0 || ^17.0.0" from @jsonforms/react@2.5.2
npm error node_modules/@jsonforms/react
npm error   @jsonforms/react@"^2.5.0" from the root project
npm error   peer @jsonforms/react@"^2.5.2" from @jsonforms/material-renderers@2.5.2
npm error   node_modules/@jsonforms/material-renderers
npm error     @jsonforms/material-renderers@"^2.5.0" from the root project
npm error   1 more (@jsonforms/vanilla-renderers)
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@"^16.12.0 || ^17.0.0" from @jsonforms/react@2.5.2
npm error   node_modules/@jsonforms/react
npm error     @jsonforms/react@"^2.5.0" from the root project
npm error     peer @jsonforms/react@"^2.5.2" from @jsonforms/material-renderers@2.5.2
npm error     node_modules/@jsonforms/material-renderers
npm error       @jsonforms/material-renderers@"^2.5.0" from the root project
npm error     1 more (@jsonforms/vanilla-renderers)
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-27T08_32_31_482Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-27T08_32_31_482Z-debug-0.log    
(env) PS E:\ReportingBot\env\Reporting-Bot-main\authsysproject\JS> 

Even when I try to do fix the version in the package.json file than it gives a conflict in the version of some other requirement and then some else and so on. But I don't know how it is perfectly working in a currently deployed project.
